# R summarise with condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have customer data with the products they purchased and the purchase date. 
[image: Input and Output]

I want to extract a result that shows each customer and the first two fruits they purchased.

My actual set has 90000 rows with 9000 unique customers. I have tried groupby and summarise functions but I would like to be able to use summarise with condition like we use select with a where clause.
Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on the iris dataset

```
t(sapply(by(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,function(x){x[1:2]}),as.numeric))
```

Where species is your customer, and Sepal.Length is your fruit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dplyr solution, you can try this:

```
yourdata %>% 
      mutate(date = paste(date, "-2018", sep = ""), # add year to date
             date = as.Date(date, format = "%d-%b-%Y")) %>% # save date in date format
      arrange(date) %>% # sort by date
      group_by(customer) %>%
      slice(1:2) %>% # keep only first two rows (fruits) per customer
      mutate(date = c("fruit1", "fruit2")) # change date variable to fruit1/fruit2
      spread(key = date, value = fruit) %>% # spread data
```

A shorter code version (condensing the mutate-part):

```
yourdata %>% 
      mutate(date = as.Date(paste(date, "-2018", sep = ""),
                            format = "%d-%b-%Y")) %>%
      arrange(date) %>% # sort by date
      group_by(customer) %>%
      slice(1:2) %>% # keep only first two rows (fruits) per customer
      mutate(date = c("fruit1", "fruit2")) %>% # change date variable to fruit1/fruit2
      spread(key = date, value = fruit) # spread data
```

Comment: isnt there a way to check by date? something like select fruit where date = min(date)

Comment: If your data isn't already sorted by date you can arrange by date, before you do the rest. But you would have to save your date variable in a date format beforehand.

Comment: If you have a "real" date column, you can add "arrange(date)" to your code before you slice the first two rows to make sure that you really select the first two purchases in time. Is your date variable currently a character string as shown in your example?

Comment: I have added the code to include the date information, I hope this helps you.

Comment: You're welcome - did it work?

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

First order the data.table by `customer` and `date`

Then group **by** `customer` and select the frist two `fruit`s

```
> df[order(customer,date)][,.(fruit1=fruit[1],fruit2=fruit[2]),by=customer] 
   customer fruit1 fruit2
1:        A orange banana
2:        B  apple  apple
3:        C banana banana
```

Sample data

```
> df <- data.table(
+ customer = c('A','A','C','C','B','B','C','B','A'),
+ fruit = c('orange','apple','banana','orange','apple','banana','banana','apple','banana'),
+ date = c(as.Date('2018-05-04'),as.Date('2018-07-09'),as.Date('2018-01-02'),as.Date('2018-01-03'),as.Date('2018-01-02'),
+ as.Date('2018-04-05'),as.Date('2018-01-02'),as.Date('2018-01-06'),as.Date('2018-06-01'))
+ )
> df
   customer  fruit       date
1:        A orange 2018-05-04
2:        A  apple 2018-07-09
3:        C banana 2018-01-02
4:        C orange 2018-01-03
5:        B  apple 2018-01-02
6:        B banana 2018-04-05
7:        C banana 2018-01-02
8:        B  apple 2018-01-06
9:        A banana 2018-06-01
```